# not a single-group group function ORACLE

Tags: database, oracle

TABLE : http://pastie.org/6205255

How to show tutor name who has max(sum(time))?

First I tried this:

```
select max(sum(time))
from tutorial
group by tutor;
```

the answer is 5
its just shown the max time but not shown who has the time(tutor name)
i tried to add select tutor, max(sum(time)) .... but ERROR

second, I tried this: (separation between max and sum)

```
select max(x) "THE MAXIMUM"
from (
    select sum(time) x,tutor from tutorial group by tutor
);
```

answer = 5.
I tried to write `select tutor,max(x) "THE MAXIMUM" ......` but still error

ALL OF THEM HAS SAME ERROR.
THE ERROR SAYS :

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

please help me

Comment: what is `durasi` referring to? That's not shown in your pastie

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting this error - the code is working fine in this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e480/2

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, a simple way would be to just do a normal `GROUP BY`, order by the sum of the time (descending) and pick the first row;

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT SUM("time") "time", "tutor"
   FROM tutorial
   GROUP BY "tutor"
   ORDER BY "time" DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM=1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/53f53/3).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a computer today but try this.

```
with a as (
  select tutor, sum(time) sum_time
    from tutorial
    group by tutor
b as (
  select tutor, sum_time, rank() over( order by sum_time desc) RN
    from a
)
  select tutor, sum_time
    from b
    where RN = 1
```

This could return more than one row if more than one tutor ties for the top. Change rank to row_number to arbitrarily pick one.